# How to not show badge/notification on lock screen for UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I read here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-lockscreen

*Defines the badge and notifications that represent the app on the lock screen, which is shown when the system is locked.*

I dont understand why all the apps need to be represented on the lock screen? I need a very simple app to make. Why should it be on the lock screen? Any way to avoid it?

Comment: Hi, for most UWP applications, it will not be displayed on the lock screen. If a UWP application is to be displayed on the lock screen, the application needs to be adapted, and the user needs to add the application to the lock screen. So don't worry